# "if I *will* decide to do X, *will* Y happen"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, tiempos-verbales, futuro

Speaking of the contractions with both future tenses, and when none of actions is certain to happen, that is, when both are "if (future) ... then (future) ...".

Namely, I could say:

"**if** I leave this place and **if** then I return later, **will** there be any problem?"

How could I say this in Spanish?

1. Si salgo de este lugar y vuelve más tarde, ¿habrá algún problema?
2. Si saldré de este lugar y volveré mas tarde, ¿habrá algún problema?
3. Si salga yo de este lugar y vuelva mas tarde, ¿habrá algún problema?
4. Si habré salido de este lugar y (habré) vuelto mas tarde, ¿habrá algún problema?

I'm aware that there may be more than one correct variant.

Especially I'm interested to learn about the (4) - why, or why not.

Comment: "If I will decide" is not usually grammatical in English. ///4) Si **hubiese o hubiera salido** de este lugar, habría algún problema? If he had gone out, would there be a problem? Subjunctive in the first clause, conditional in the second. If I went out=Si saliera or saliese

Answer (score 1):

Si salgo de este lugar ahora y luego vuelvo más tarde, ¿ hay, habrá o habría algún problema?

- Si salgo de este lugar y vuelvo más tarde, ¿hay, habrá ó habría algún problema?
  (no se utiliza vuelve sino vuelvo)
- Si saliese de este lugar y volviese mas tarde, ¿habría algún problema?
- Si saliera de este lugar y volviera mas tarde, ¿habría algún problema?
  (Futuro de Subjuntivo hubiere, no se suele utilizar, hubiere algún problema)

(Saliera ó saliese Imperfecto de Subjuntivo)
(Volviera ó volviese Imperfecto de Subjuntivo)

Utilizar la forma de futuro del Subjuntivo de volver en estos casos,
volviere
volvieres
volviere
volviéremos
volviereis
volvieren
es posible, pero no es lo recomendable, no suena bien.

- Si hubiere salido de este lugar y (hubiere) vuelto mas tarde, ¿hubiere algún problema? (Estos tiempos en subjuntivo son muy puntuales y por lo general es raro utilizarlos)

Comment: No. `Si salgo de este lugar *ahora* y luego vuelvo más tarde` ==> de donde te sacaste "ahora"? En mi pregunta no hay "ahora", tampoco se lo implica. Se pregunta sobre "en futuro"

Comment: tampoco intiendo tu respuesta - solamenta has repetido mis 3 o 4 preguntas. Y que?

Comment: "if  I l eave this place now..." Si salgo... tu estas utilizando oraciones condicionales con ‘si’ en indicativo y subjuntivo.

Comment: My mistake - there must not have been "now". I meant "if I will (in the future, if...) leave this place....". Note that "if I left this place..." isn't what I'm asking about

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, "saldré", "salga" and "habré salido" can't precede "si".

Before "si" you can use any indicativo tense except conditional and future. You can't use the present tense of the subjunctive or the perfect past of the subjunctive either.

Also,

**Vuelve** más tarde (that person)

**Vuelvo** más tarde (me)

1. Si salgo de aquí y vuelvo más tarde, ¿hay algún problema?
2. Si salgo de aquí y vuelvo más tarde, ¿habrá algún problema?
3. Si salgo de aquí y vuelvo más tarde, ¿habría algún problema?

Since I'm using indicative tenses, the nuance here is that this is a real possibility I'm contemplating.
They're all common, natural, and very similar.

1 would probably be translated as "is there any problem if..."

2 would probably be translated as "will there be any problem if..."

3 would probably be translated as "would there be any problem if..."

You can also add another layer of uncertainty if you use the subjunctive, which is what Diego said.
I'd suggest phrasing it this way since you placed an emphasis on both actions being unlikely (though using indicative would be grammatically correct as well).

Si saliera/saliese de aquí y volviera más tarde, ¿habría algún problema?

With subjunctive the most natural way would be to use conditional afterwards.
Saliera and saliese are the same conjugation. Saliese is slightly less common, but they're identical in their grammar usage and nuance.

The subjunctive future is only used in legal contexts and such to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional sentences in Spanish follow a very similar logic to that of English conditionals. Your question is about what English calls a first conditional form. The if-part uses present tense; the then-part uses future tense. (Tense does not always equal time: the if-part might refer to the present or the future.) This is exactly the same in Spanish:

*Si salgo de este lugar y vuelvo más tarde, ¿habrá algún problema?*

That is the only one of your alternatives that is grammatically correct. You cannot use future tense in an if-then structure like that.

*Si* + future tense is not impossible in Spanish, but it is very rare. It appears in sentences like the following:

*Si pronto tendré dinero, ¿por qué no puedo planear un viaje alrededor del mundo?*

In this case the first part is not a real if-condition: what you are saying is not "*if* I will soon have money" but more like "*since* I will soon have money"; and the second part is also not a consequence of a condition being fulfilled.